# I would like to import PostGIS' Raster Layer into QGIS using SQL. Is there a way?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, postgis-raster

I imported PostGIS Raster Layer using PyQGIS. Can I apply SQL to it?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "user", "password")
uri.setDataSource("public", "landsat", "rast")
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(), "landsat", "postgresraster")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer)
```

SQL

```
 SELECT st_union(st_clip(t1.rast, t2.geom, '65535'::integer::double precision, true)) AS rast
   FROM landsat t1,
    ( SELECT dem30.rid,
            st_envelope(dem30.rast) AS geom
           FROM dem30) t2
  WHERE st_intersects(t1.rast, t2.geom);
```

Comment: Can you create a view?

Comment: I created the View, but QGIS throws an error. There are no errors when creating the table. But I wish it was possible with SQL

Comment: Please, edit your question with the view and the error message

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in DbManager?  I forget if DbManager works with raster properly. It used to not.  You could create a view on the Db side and add that view as a layer in QGIS.  I've done that before and that works.